# html send to my email when click sumbit button

Tags: javascript, css, forms, popup

I'm making a feedback popup. I want to make sure that the text in the input can come to my email when users press the submit button. I tried it in the way below, but the text in the input doesn't come to me by e-mail.

```html
<div class="popup" style="z-index: 10">
  <div class="contentBox">
    <!--close_btn=======-->
    <button id="close">X</button>
    <div class="feedbackBox" style="padding-top: 3px">
      <strong>Give feedback</strong>
      <p style="margin: 10.96px">
        Таны үлдээсэн сэтгэгдэл бидэнд маш их тус болох болно.
      </p>
    </div>
    <!--emojies========-->
    <div class="emojiBox">
      <div class="emoji" style="margin-left: 56.81px">
        <img src="icons/face emoji/smiling-face-with-heart-eyes.png" alt="" />
        <p>Best</p>
      </div>

      <div class="emoji">
        <img src="icons/face emoji/happy-face-with-enlarged-eyes.png" alt="" />
        <p>Good</p>
      </div>
      <div class="emoji">
        <img src="icons/face emoji/expressionless-face.png" alt="" />
        <p>Bad</p>
      </div>
      <div class="emoji">
        <img src="icons/face emoji/face-with-steam-from-nose.png" alt="" />
        <p>Terrible</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--feedback-write==-->
    <div class="wrie_feedback">
      <p>Үлдэхийг хүссэн санал бодол, сэтгэгдлээ доор үлдээнэ үү.</p>
      <input type="text" maxlength="200" required />
    </div>
    <!--send-btn========-->
    <button id="send_feedback">Явуулах</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't send an email directly from HTML. You need to have a backend which sends the email. However you can use `<form action="mailto:someone@example.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">` to open the email tool set in the browser. https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_mail

Comment: How are you sending this email?  How are you including this text in that operation?  There's no code here which does any of that.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.